# Centered block shifting after CSS transition with scale transform in all Browsers (I give up)

Tags: css, scaletransform

Reference the detailed treatment of:

[Image shifting/jumping after CSS transition effect with scale transform in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825098/image-shifting-jumping-after-css-transition-effect-with-scale-transform-in-firef)

I have tried everything suggested there, but I still get a right-shifting of my centered block after the CSS transition effect has completed.

BTW, I really need `transform:scale` because I call this in my resize Event code; I cannot afford the time to redraw Canvas' Context during `onresize`.

**Critical CSS:**

```
#container {
    display:   block;

    margin:    0 auto;
    width:     30.00em;
    height:    22.50em;

    border:    0.30em solid #cd853f;

    overflow:  hidden;
}
```

**Elsewhere** in my `$(window).bind('resize', function() {...}` call, I have:

```
theContainer.css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + theScale + ", " + theScale + ")");
```

together with the appropriate prefixes for other Browsers.

Just added my 1st jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/yL2td3r2/ ) ... as you shrink the window size horizontally, you see the bordered image scale correctly. But with further window shrinkage, the bordered image continues to scale properly **but** you **also** see the bordered image **slide off to the right**. **???**

**EDITED: Oct 1 and Oct 6**

*Trying to put the above sliding off to the right in different words ... it appears that somehow the window's width is falsely computed to be larger than it is ... the bordered image is scaling correctly, but with the incorrect (larger) window width, the bordered image is sliding or shifting to the right because the DOM's CSS code is centering it.*

*Anyway, these are my impressions, FWIW.*

***Am at the point where I give up on this for multiple Browsers. I tried using `transform: translate and scale together`, with zero success.***

Comment: @aakash Or simply add it using an SO snippet, its the document icon with the `<>` in it. Better to keep everything in one place. _This_ place.

Comment: @JohnLove - Are you just trying to add responsive behavior to your image to adopt to different screen sizes, or are you trying to achieve something else ?

Comment: @DavidDomain - my  http://jsfiddle.net/johnlove/yL2td3r2 is a weak instrument to describe what I need. What I need is transform:scale(x,x) in order to "cosmetically" scale the images. And the reason is best depicted by looking at http://www.lovesongforever.com/50. There you will see a "camera shutter" jQuery special effect. The problem is not scaling the .jpeg images which are in the <ul>, but scaling the camera shutter image which is created via var shutterImg = new Image().

Comment: Please note the added EDIT in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Analysing your JSFiddle, I tried to get the same result with a different approach. I feel like using scale transformations may not be the best answer, so I tried using only max-width and removing the javascript.

If you need a special treatment for small screens, you may want to consider using media queries

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

New css:

```
/* #container ul li img */
 #container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30.00em;
    max-width: 90%;
    border: 0.30em solid #cd853f;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#container img {
    /* match specs to #container */
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cv42bk0q/1/

I hope it helps.

Ps.: If it is possible to solve a problem using only CSS, I highly recommend you to do so, as the code gets cleaner and the browser calculates everything for you, reducing the amount of bugs and improving performance.

Comment: May I suggest adding `vertical-align: middle` to `#container img` to remove the gap underneath the image? Good answer anyway. +1

Comment: I really appreciate your response, in particular, the vertical-align: middle. Also, I wish to the stars that I could use just CSS. There may be a way, but I really need -transform: scale(xx, yy) somehow or another in order to scale the moving shutter in http://lovesongforever.com/50.

Comment: Please notice the added EDIT in the OP.